# Upgrading Lync to Skype for Business

Tags: skype, lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I am attempting to update Lync 2013 (15.0.4420.1017) to Skype for Business.

I have downloaded and installed the following updates as [described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3054791):

- lpksp2013-kb2817427-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe
- lynchelploc2013-kb2889853-fullfile-x86-glb.exe
- lync2013-kb3054946-fullfile-x86-glb.exe
- mso2013-kb3054853-fullfile-x86-glb.exe
- lyncmso2013-kb2889923-fullfile-x86-glb.exe

The updates run successfully, but Lync isn't updating.

What can I do next?

Comment: Weird. Mine was automatically updated.

Comment: I have no idea how to trigger the updates in Windows 10. Getting latest updates returns nothing for Lync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following update was also required: proplussp2013-kb2817430-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe

[Found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=42017).